# OS X Photos show old photos as new

Tags: ios, photos, macos, import

A couple of days ago I noticed that Photos on El Capitan shows already imported photos as new photos, when I select an iOS device. The iOS devices are synced with the Photos library and contain the albums local. This happens only for a few photos, not all of them.

My Photos library contain a couple of thousand photos. You will notice in the screenshot below that only 11 photos on my iPad are **new**. However, those photos are years **old** and got already imported into an album.

[image]

I tried following:

- Started Photos with <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> and repaired the library
- Imported the photos to a fake album and deleted them afterwards

Unfortunately, nothing helped. Does anyone have an idea, what I can do, to get rid of the **old** or **new** photos?